# How to use direflow-component offline without internet?

Tags: reactjs, microservices, web-component, micro-frontend

I'm using direflow-component to generate reusable React web-components.
It seems that the generated script "direflowBundle.js" is requesting many resources from internet.
I have tried to use it offline without internet but it's not working at all.
So, is there any way to use direflow-component offline without connecting to internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an answer from Direflow owner on GitHub!

Simply, yes, it is possible by tweaking a bit:

[Link of the issue on Direflow GitHub repository.](https://github.com/Silind-Software/direflow/issues/86)